# insert form data including image into mysql by not using PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, blob

> I'm new in coding. I have successful connection with DB. And i want to insert form data including
>     image into mysql.  How can i do it?

```
app.post('/insert', function (request, response) {
    var card = {
        'fullName': req.body.$name,
        'compName': req.body.$comp,
        'memPos': req.body.$pos,
        'mobNum': req.body.$mobnum,
        'telNum': req.body.$telnum,
        'faxNum': req.body.$faxnum,
        'addr': req.body.$addr,
        'email': req.body.$email,
        'homePage': req.body.$hpage,
        'typeID': req.body.$typeID,
      //  'cardImg': req.body.$cardimg,
        'idFbook': req.body.$idFbook,
        'idTweet': req.body.$idTweet,
        'idSkype': req.body.$idSkype,
        'idKakao': req.body.$idKakao,
        'note': req.body.$note
    };
    var query = connection.query('insert into cardinfo set ?', card, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(query);
        res.send(200, 'success');
    });
        });
```

Comment: You can insert binary data into your DB (data type BLOB). But I would not recommend this. Save the file on a special folder on your server and store the filename in your DB.

Comment: Thats the common approach! Store the filename.